Emoji Feedback in Microsoft Teams AI Chatbot
I have a generative LLM that I communicate with via REST APIs. I am not using any native OpenAI or Azure objects to utilize the enable_feedback_loop available in the AI Bot Framework.
I've looked around for some videos and setups but I cannot find a way to implement the functionality below:

For each message returned by the bot, allow the user to react to two different emojis.
(, )
Upon clicking on these emojis, open up a text window that allows the user to enter their feedback regarding the response.

I've only seen this available via the enable_feedback_loop parameter in the AI Bot Framework, but I cannot use this functionality since my generative model is hosted externally.

Any ideas? Still haven't found a solution.

I would just send messages inside Adaptive Card with actions type set to Action.ShowCard which expands after click and allow to type a message, then submit it,
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.5",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Message title",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "wrap": true,
            "style": "heading"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Message content ...",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Feedback",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "wrap": true,
            "style": "heading"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "label": "Enter comment",
                        "id": "CommentVal"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "label": "Enter comment",
                        "id": "CommentVal"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

preview gif of the card
